# Strange CSS issue - background attribute is not working without image height

Tags: html, css, image, background

I need to set the image `height` everytime I'm using `background: url('images/something.jpg')[..];`

Fe.

HTML:

```
<div class="someImage"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.someImage {
    background: url('images/something.jpg') no-repeat top;
}
```

The above example should work... but image won't display until I add an image `height` attribute to the CSS style class:

```
.someImage {
    background: url('images/something.jpg') no-repeat top;
    height: 25px;
}
```

And then my image appear on the website...

Why does it happend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because without content, a div has no height, background image or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since your div is empty it has no height..

The image you use is applied as a background, so it does not affect the size.. it just fits whatever space is available at the div.

When you explicitly set the height, you create room for the image to appear..